# Effect on CSS and fancybox add-on

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-3

I will try to be brief, I made a design that when I passed the mouse through a box with an image, it was raised a bit using a css effect and I showed two buttons, one of them when I clicked open a video using the fancybox plugin 3.

When I close the video, the box remains with the effect pasted until I put the mouse back in the box, as shown in the image.

How can I make it so that once the video is closed, the image of the box returns to normal?

I make a copy of the code that I used in the style sheet and the fancybox code 3

javascript:

```
$(".imagen-evento").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".imagen").toggleClass("imagenHover");
    $(this).find(".caption").toggleClass("captionHover");
});

$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
    buttons : [
        'close'
    ],
    afterClose : function(instance, current) {
        $(".imagen-evento").each(function(){
            $(this).find(".imagen").removeClass('imagenHover');
            $(this).find(".caption").removeClass('captionHover');
        });
    }
});
```

css:

```
.imagenHover {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-47px);
    transform: translateY(-47px);
}
.captionHover {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

html:

```
    <div class="card">
        <div class="imagen-evento">
            <div class="imagen">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="/assets/images/p1.png" alt="Evento 1">
            </div>
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a href="/evento-en-chillout" class="btn text-lowercase">Más información</a>
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S4OTzltOzm0" data-fancybox="gallery" class="btn btn-sm text-lowercase btn-right">Ver video</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row detalles">
                <div class="col-3 fecha">
                    <div class="dia text-center uppercase">17</div>
                    <div class="mes text-center">nov</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9 descripcion pl-0">
                    <div class="lugar uppercase"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> Chill Out</div>
                    <div class="personas-lista"><i class="fa fa-male" aria-hidden="true"></i> 180 personas en lista</div>
                    <div class="tiempo-lista time-list"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Tiempo de lista: <div class="tiempo d-inline-flex" data-time="2018/01/15 02:21:40"></div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the option "afterClose" of fancybox 3 I try to remove the class that contains the effect in css but when I see the box, it does not have that class but the effect is still pasted as if it were active.

ok, better explain with an example ... in the following link click on the "watch video" button and when you close the video the image will be raised again and this should not happen.

https://jsfiddle.net/greermurray/9jt5Lzq3/1/

Comment: There is no need to remove these class names, because they will be removed automatically. Try this demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/goLxPe - click image, then move cursor away so it is not over the image, then close fancyBox. If you would not move cursor away, then hover style will be applied.

Comment: ok, better explain with an example ...

in the following link click on the "watch video" button and when you close the video the image will be raised again and this should not happen.  https://jsfiddle.net/greermurray/9jt5Lzq3/1/

Comment: Simply set `backFocus : false`, because the script places focus on the clicked element https://jsfiddle.net/9jt5Lzq3/2/

Comment: ohhh !!! I had not seen that option! thank you very much! How can I put a reputation point?

Comment: Do not worry, I am glad I was able to help.